# Getting "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" on all dialog forms

Tags: 2010, modal-dialog, iframe

**Environment**: SharePoint Server 2010

We have a web application, in which there is only 1 site collection with few subsites in it.

The problem is all the modal dialog forms when opened get error message(*refer screen shot*). Dialog forms such as check in, approve/reject a page, more options from site actions etc.

There are solutions on the web like placing `<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server"  />`, but that can be used in SP 2013.

Also other Web application in the farm works nicely.

In what direction should I continue investigation? And has anyone come across similar issue.

[image]

Comment: Are using any custom master page?

Comment: Yes we are using custom master pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I managed to solve the problem.

`Open IIS` > `Find your site` > `HTTP Response`

If there is `X-Frame-Options:Deny`, Then just remove it or set value to "SAMEORIGIN".

[image]

Removing `X-Frame-Options` worked wonders for me.

> **Note**: To know more about `X-Frame-Options` I recommend reading [Combating ClickJacking With X-Frame-Options](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options/) and [Mitigating
>   framesniffing with the X-Frame-Options header](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2694329/mitigating-framesniffing-with-the-x-frame-options-header).